# iPhone sdk: Core-plot How to display y Axis on the right side on

Tags: iphone, sdk, core-plot

iPhone sdk: Core-plot How to display y Axis on the right side on??

I am now using Core-plot in iphone sdk ,

This is what i have done so far

[image]

but i want to put the Yaxis in right hand side.

i have enable the allowsuserInteractive

```
**plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction=NO;
volumePlotSpace.allowsUserInteraction=YES;**
```

But i want X axis and Y axis always stay the right hand side and bottom,

Whatever user scale big or small....

like this:
[image]

Answer (score 14):

Which version of Core-Plot are you using?

Core-Plot 0.9 allows you to set constraints on axes positions. A code line like this should do the job:

```
// 'graph' is your CPTXYGraph object
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
// move axis to the rightmost position
axisSet.yAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithUpperOffset:0];
// put ticks on the right hand side of the axis
axisSet.yAxis.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;
// add some padding to the right so that labels are actually visible
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight = 20.0f;
```

I'm not aware in which version this was introduced, but at least for Core-Plot 0.2.2 the procedure was a bit different. I don't have it on my box now so I can't check, but this is how to fix Y axis on the left hand side:

```
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
axisSet.yAxis.isFloatingAxis = YES;
// fixed lower constraint, no upper constraint
CPConstraints yConstraints = {CPConstraintFixed, CPConstraintNone};
axisSet.yAxis.constraints = yConstraints;
```

I guess that for right hand side yConstraints should be `{CPConstraintNone, CPConstraintFixed}`.

Comment: I still have some question about the core-plot,

Comment: i have another question , please see this link, thank you >.<
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819472/iphone-core-plot-chart-zoom-in-zoom-out-y-axis-bigger-y-axis-smaller

Comment: isFloatingAxis is removed in 0.9 version, what should i do? >.<

Comment: @ayoy hello sir ,how to make a graph plz give me any link or tutorials  or any sample code ..please help .thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1):

In coreplot 1.5.1 , you can use **CPTConstraints** to set the Y axis on left or right,  OR , set the X axis on bottom or top

```
 yAxis.axisConstraints = CPTConstraints(lowerOffset: CGFloat(0.0))
```

**lowerOffset** means left(Y axis) or bottom(X axis);
**upperOffset** means right(Y axis) or top(X axis)