# iPhone Core-plot: Chart Zoom In Zoom out, Y axis Bigger, Y axis Smaller

Tags: iphone, charts, core-plot

I am now using Core-plot for iPhone chart Development.
But it has some requirement i can not reach.

I am now using **CorePlot 0.4**, example code **AAPLot** to develop

Please have a look the following image, then you will know what is my problem
Thank you very much...

I really need help for this problem,
thank you

[image]

[image]

i want my result like this application

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I see several questions here:

1. Y-axis scale: Try the `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic` labeling policy on your y-axis. If that doesn't give you enough control, use a different labeling policy and use a plot space delegate to adjust the labeling parameters as the user zooms in and out.
2. Disappearing x-axis: Make it a "floating" axis. For example,

   ```
   x.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
   ```
3. Maximum zoom level: Use the `globalXRange` and `globalYRange` plot space properties. If you need more control, you can use a plot space delegate.
4. Scroll bars: This isn't directly supported. You could use a plot space delegate to update the scroll bar position.

Comment: Is that possible user touch the chart

Comment: There's no touch delegate built into Core Plot for this plot type yet. See the discussion here: http://groups.google.com/group/coreplot-discuss/browse_thread/thread/766fed30536f40a8/11274c6465d56d10#11274c6465d56d10

Comment: now i am using the latest CorePlot with 1.0- 1.1.
CorePlot Framework is not supporting a interactive chart which contains more than 1000 data. When user try to zoom in or zoom out on 1000 datas chart, the performance became really slow.